# CSS Transform using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Please see attached codepen example. I am trying to fly a div called .mail-content into view, which I have positioned absolutely out of view. I am trying to fly it in by clicking on .super-btn, and then I want to send it back out-from-view by clicking on .close-btn-mail. The JS is not working for me. Any advice?

[Updated Code Pen](http://codepen.io/alikingravi/pen/KpYQKr)

```js
$('.super-btn').on('click', function(){
   $('.mail-content').css({"transform":"translate(100%,100%)"});
  });

 $('.close-btn-mail').on('click', function(){
  $('.mail-content').css({"transform":"translate(-100%,-100%)"});
  
 });
```

```css
.mail-content{
 background: rgb(0,0,0);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: -100%;
 left: -100%;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
         transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .mail-content h1{
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  color: #fff;

 }
 .mail-content p{
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
        color: #fff;
 }

 .close-btn-mail{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 80px;
  right: 80px;
 }
```

```html
<a class="super-btn" href="#">Fly-in</a>

<div class="mail-content">
    <h1>mail-content should fly in</h1>
    <p>and then fly back to where it came from</p>
    <a class="close-btn-mail" href="">Send Back</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to import jQuery.

Comment: Works when you add jQuery. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry, using codepen for the first time, but I have obviously added jQuery while testing locally. The div flies in fine, but does not fly back out. Im wondering if my JS syntax is ok? Do I need an if statement? or a document.onload() function?

Comment: Oh I see what you meaaannnn .... Ive added jQuery in codepen and its working.....but its not working on my machine, the div is flying in but not going back .....

Comment: @developerNoob Well, that would imply that there's a key difference between your basic working example and your local code. Look closely for anything seemingly-insignificant you may not have posted.

Comment: Haha! The issue was that the href="" on close-btn-mail was set to nothing ... as it can be seen in the last line of the snippet .... Really appreciate all your help. One question though, if I want to apply the same effect to multiple divs, will this JS still be adequate? Meaning I should just use the .on(Click, function)?